# Optimize MYSQL query with MAX()

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, max, phpactiverecord

I have a MYSQL query that i need to optimize, it worked great in my testing enviroment but against a larger database it is way to slow

i'm using PHP activerecord as my db-handler.

```
Users:
userId | userName | gameId 
-------+----------+--------
   1   |  John    |    1
   2   |  Sally   |    1
   3   |  Mike    |    2
   4   |  Lex     |    1

Scores:
id | userId | gameId | score  |   added   | 
---+--------+---------+-------+-----------+
 1 |   2    |   1     |  300  |   time
 2 |   2    |   1     |  325  |
 3 |   1    |   1     |  200  |
 4 |   1    |   1     |  400  |
 5 |   4    |   1     |  100  |

extra_fields:
id | score_id | fieldname | fieldvalue |
---+----------+-----------+------------+
1  |     1    |  level    |   5        |
2  |     1    |   image   |  icon.jpg  |
3  |     2    |  level    |   7        |
4  |     2    |   image   | smilie.jpg |
5  |     3    |  level    |   5        |
6  |     3    |  image    |  hello.jpg |
7  |     4    |  level    |   1        |
8  |     4    |  image    |  fun.png   |
9  |     5    |  level    |   3        |
10 |     5    |  image    |  mfw.png   |
```

Now here is the problem, i want to select the highest scores from each user , and then fetch the associated extra values.
So in the example db above the result would look like this:

A request for users in game 1 (where gameId = 1):

```
1 -> username: John ; Score: 400 ; level : 1 ; image : fun.png
2 -> username: Sally ; Score: 325 ; level : 7 ; image : smilie.jpg
3 -> username: Lex ; Score: 100 ; level 3 ; image : mfw.png
```

Now this is what i have:

```
"SELECT *  FROM leaderboard_users a JOIN  (
    SELECT d1.* 
    FROM leaderboard_scores d1  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN leaderboard_scores d2
    ON (d1.userId = d2.userId AND d1.score < d2.score AND d1.added < d2.added) 
        WHERE d2.id is null AND d1.gameId = " . intval($this->gameId) . "
        AND DATEDIFF(NOW() , d1.added) <= " . intval($this->calcPeriod) . " 
    )b 
    ON b.userId = a.userId
    GROUP BY b.userId
    ORDER BY b.score DESC
    LIMIT " . $this->limitWithOffset . " , " . $this->limit;
```

and from that i get username, score and score_id i then do another query to find all extra fields (if any)

```
$extraValues = \extraFields::find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'score_id = ?',
                        $j->id)
                    ));
```

Im guessing what takes time is the JOIN statement since i join all records in the score table ( 30k+ ) which seems crazy.

Does anyone know how i can optimize this? 
Or is my table layout all wrong and needs to be changed?

Edit (Explain for RaviH)

```
id  select_type     table       type    possible_keys           key                     key_len     ref                     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>  ALL     NULL                    NULL                    NULL        NULL                    1554    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY         a           eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY                 4           b.userId                1   
2   DERIVED         d1          ALL     NULL                    NULL                    NULL        NULL                    41644   Using where
2   DERIVED         d2          ref     leaderboard_scores_FI_1 leaderboard_scores_FI_1 4           lechuck_se.d1.userId    12      Using where; Not exists
```

Comment: Run your query with "EXPLAIN" and post the result.

Comment: Edited my answer with the explain result!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fetching all rows from `leaderboard_users` and `leaderboard_scores` tables leading to cross join between user table and scores self join result. Temporary result of these cross joins is huge. Therefore it has slowed down. It will get slower as more number of rows are added to users and scores tables.

Try the query below:

```
"SELECT * FROM leaderboard_users u JOIN (
    SELECT userId, MAX(score) FROM leaderboard_scores 
        WHERE gameId=" . intval($this->gameId) . " AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) <= " . intval($this->calcPeriod) . " GROUP BY userId) s 
    ON u.userId = s.userId"
```

Query speed can be further improved if you can avoid the dynamically calculated `DATEDIFF` somehow. I cannot provide a generic solution for this because it depends on your requirements and the database design.

Hope this helps!